# Opencart add products in admin panel

Tags: php, json, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I am developing a module for opencart 2.2.0.0 and I copied some of the basic functionality but mine isn't working.

I got to the point where the view is displaying the product form but in the original module the products which are available are shown and with my module they don't.

Original code from admin:

**Controller**

```
class ControllerModuleFeatured extends Controller {
private $error = array();

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('module/featured');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('extension/module');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
            $this->model_extension_module->addModule('featured', $this->request->post);
        } else {
            $this->model_extension_module->editModule($this->request->get['module_id'], $this->request->post);
        }

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true));
    }

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
    $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
    $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');

    $data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');
    $data['entry_product'] = $this->language->get('entry_product');
    $data['entry_limit'] = $this->language->get('entry_limit');
    $data['entry_width'] = $this->language->get('entry_width');
    $data['entry_height'] = $this->language->get('entry_height');
    $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');

    $data['help_product'] = $this->language->get('help_product');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['name'])) {
        $data['error_name'] = $this->error['name'];
    } else {
        $data['error_name'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['width'])) {
        $data['error_width'] = $this->error['width'];
    } else {
        $data['error_width'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['height'])) {
        $data['error_height'] = $this->error['height'];
    } else {
        $data['error_height'] = '';
    }

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_module'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
    );

    if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('module/featured', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true)
        );
    } else {
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('module/featured', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], true)
        );
    }

    if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/featured', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true);
    } else {
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/featured', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], true);
    }

    $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true);

    if (isset($this->request->get['module_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
        $module_info = $this->model_extension_module->getModule($this->request->get['module_id']);
    }

    $data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];

    if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
        $data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['name'] = $module_info['name'];
    } else {
        $data['name'] = '';
    }

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $data['products'] = array();

    if (!empty($this->request->post['product'])) {
        $products = $this->request->post['product'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info['product'])) {
        $products = $module_info['product'];
    } else {
        $products = array();
    }

    foreach ($products as $product_id) {
        $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

        if ($product_info) {
            $data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
                'name'       => $product_info['name']
            );
        }
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['limit'])) {
        $data['limit'] = $this->request->post['limit'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['limit'] = $module_info['limit'];
    } else {
        $data['limit'] = 5;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['width'])) {
        $data['width'] = $this->request->post['width'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['width'] = $module_info['width'];
    } else {
        $data['width'] = 200;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['height'])) {
        $data['height'] = $this->request->post['height'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['height'] = $module_info['height'];
    } else {
        $data['height'] = 200;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['status'])) {
        $data['status'] = $this->request->post['status'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['status'] = $module_info['status'];
    } else {
        $data['status'] = '';
    }

    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('module/featured', $data));
}

protected function validate() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/featured')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 64)) {
        $this->error['name'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['width']) {
        $this->error['width'] = $this->language->get('error_width');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['height']) {
        $this->error['height'] = $this->language->get('error_height');
    }

    return !$this->error;
}
}
```

**View**

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" form="form-featured" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_edit; ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-featured" class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>          
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-product"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $help_product; ?>"><?php echo $entry_product; ?></span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="product_name" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_product; ?>" id="input-product" class="form-control" />
              <div id="featured-product" class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
                <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                <div id="featured-product<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
                  <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-limit"><?php echo $entry_limit; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="limit" value="<?php echo $limit; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_limit; ?>" id="input-limit" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-width"><?php echo $entry_width; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="width" value="<?php echo $width; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_width; ?>" id="input-width" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_width) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_width; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-height"><?php echo $entry_height; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="height" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_height; ?>" id="input-height" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_height) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_height; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-status"><?php echo $entry_status; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="status" id="input-status" class="form-control">
                <?php if ($status) { ?>
                <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('input[name=\'product_name\']').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item['name'],
                        value: item['product_id']
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(item) {
        $('input[name=\'product_name\']').val('');

        $('#featured-product' + item['value']).remove();

        $('#featured-product').append('<div id="featured-product' + item['value'] + '"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> ' + item['label'] + '<input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="' + item['value'] + '" /></div>');  
    }
});

$('#featured-product').delegate('.fa-minus-circle', 'click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
//--></script></div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Which results in:
[image]

And here is my module code:

**Controller**

```
class ControllerModulePopular extends Controller {
    private $error = array(); 

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('module/popular');
    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));
    $this->load->model('extension/module');

    // Validate and check for errors
    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
        if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
            $this->model_extension_module->addModule('popular', $this->request->post);
        } else {
            $this->model_extension_module->editModule($this->request->get['module_id'], $this->request->post);
        }

        $this->cache->delete('product');
        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
    }

    // Set language
    $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    $data['text_edit'] = $this->language->get('text_edit');
    $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
    $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');

    $data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');
    $data['entry_product'] = $this->language->get('entry_product');
    $data['entry_limit'] = $this->language->get('entry_limit');
    $data['entry_width'] = $this->language->get('entry_width');
    $data['entry_height'] = $this->language->get('entry_height');
    $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');

    $data['help_product'] = $this->language->get('help_product');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');

    if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['name'])) {
        $data['error_name'] = $this->error['name'];
    } else {
        $data['error_name'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['width'])) {
        $data['error_width'] = $this->error['width'];
    } else {
        $data['error_width'] = '';
    }

    if (isset($this->error['height'])) {
        $data['error_height'] = $this->error['height'];
    } else {
        $data['error_height'] = '';
    }

    // Breadcrumbs
    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/dashboard', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_module'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
    );

    if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('module/popular', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL')
        );
    } else {
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('module/popular', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], 'SSL')
        );          
    }

    // Setting the action variable depending upon the presence of module_id. 
    if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/popular', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');
    } else {
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('module/popular', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], 'SSL');
    }

    $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL');

    // If the module_id is present in URL and the action is not POST then this will fetch the module information based on the module_id.
    if (isset($this->request->get['module_id']) && ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')) {
        $module_info = $this->model_extension_module->getModule($this->request->get['module_id']);
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
        $data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['name'] = $module_info['name'];
    } else {
        $data['name'] = '';
    }

    // Products
    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $data['products'] = array();

    if (!empty($this->request->post['product'])) {
        $products = $this->request->post['product'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info['product'])) {
        $products = $module_info['product'];
    } else {
        $products = array();
    }

    foreach ($products as $product_id) {
        $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

        if ($product_info) {
            $data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id' => $product_info['product_id'],
                'name'       => $product_info['name']
            );
        }
    }
    // End products

    if (isset($this->request->post['limit'])) {
        $data['limit'] = $this->request->post['limit'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['limit'] = $module_info['limit'];
    } else {
        $data['limit'] = 5;
    }   

    if (isset($this->request->post['width'])) {
        $data['width'] = $this->request->post['width'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['width'] = $module_info['width'];
    } else {
        $data['width'] = 200;
    }   

    if (isset($this->request->post['height'])) {
        $data['height'] = $this->request->post['height'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['height'] = $module_info['height'];
    } else {
        $data['height'] = 200;
    }       

    if (isset($this->request->post['status'])) {
        $data['status'] = $this->request->post['status'];
    } elseif (!empty($module_info)) {
        $data['status'] = $module_info['status'];
    } else {
        $data['status'] = '';
    }

    // Loading the header, footer and column_left controller and then setting the output with the $data. Finally HTML will be constructed from the template/data.
    $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
    $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

    $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('module/popular.tpl', $data));
}

protected function validate() {
    if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'module/popular')) {
        $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
    }

    if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 64)) {
        $this->error['name'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['width']) {
        $this->error['width'] = $this->language->get('error_width');
    }

    if (!$this->request->post['height']) {
        $this->error['height'] = $this->language->get('error_height');
    }

    return !$this->error;
    }
  }
```

**View**

```
<?php echo $header; ?><?php echo $column_left; ?>
<div id="content">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" form="form-popular" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_save; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
        <a href="<?php echo $cancel; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_cancel; ?>" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-reply"></i></a></div>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> <?php echo $text_edit; ?></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-popular" class="form-horizontal">
        <!-- Entry Name -->
         <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- Entry Name -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-product"><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $help_product; ?>"><?php echo $entry_product; ?></span></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="product_name" value="" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_product; ?>" id="input-product" class="form-control" />
              <div id="featured-product" class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
                <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
                <div id="featured-product<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> <?php echo $product['name']; ?>
                  <input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>" />
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- Entry Limit -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-limit"><?php echo $entry_limit; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="limit" value="<?php echo $limit; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_limit; ?>" id="input-limit" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- Entry Limit -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-width"><?php echo $entry_width; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="width" value="<?php echo $width; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_width; ?>" id="input-width" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_width) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_width; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-height"><?php echo $entry_height; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="height" value="<?php echo $height; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_height; ?>" id="input-height" class="form-control" />
              <?php if ($error_height) { ?>
              <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_height; ?></div>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-status"><?php echo $entry_status; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <select name="status" id="input-status" class="form-control">
                <?php if ($status) { ?>
                <option value="1" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="1"><?php echo $text_enabled; ?></option>
                <option value="0" selected="selected"><?php echo $text_disabled; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('input[name=\'product_name\']').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                response($.map(json, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item['name'],
                        value: item['product_id']
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    select: function(item) {
        $('input[name=\'product_name\']').val('');

        $('#featured-product' + item['value']).remove();

        $('#featured-product').append('<div id="featured-product' + item['value'] + '"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i> ' + item['label'] + '<input type="hidden" name="product[]" value="' + item['value'] + '" /></div>');  
    }
});

$('#featured-product').delegate('.fa-minus-circle', 'click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
//--></script>
</div>
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

Why am I not able to choose products from the available list?

P.S. sorry for the long code examples but I didn't knew what's needed to explain my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed a line of code in Controller file,

Add below line

```
$data['token'] = $this->session->data['token'];
```

Above `$this->load->model('catalog/product');` in Controller file

Comment: I figured it out a couple of days ago but thanks for reviewing the code!!!